# Vue SPA Authentication with Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, single-page-application

I'm currently building a Vue SPA with Laravel as my backend provider. I have reached a dilemma which I am yet to solve and it is thus:

a) I'm using Laravel Passport to authenticate my users. However, I'm getting a 302 status code whenever I issue a POST request to the Authentication route (/login). What would be the correct method to override this in the LoginController? A laravel_token is being associated with any requests I made to my API routes, which suggests that when I log in using the conventional login form, Passport is creating a token each time the request is sent.

b) How would I enforce policies in Vue? My first thought would be to route different levels of users e.g. Admins and Users via subdomains. Then I would use middleware on the subdomains and create new instances of Vue & VueRouter on the respective subdomains. My past experience says that this might be overkill and I find myself asking the questions here.

Being a lone developer means that I don't necessarily have anyone to discuss this with and studying Computer Science really doesn't help with Web-based programming ;)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you override the login passport. Because the default is ` oauth/token ` https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/passport

Comment: Will posting to that endpoint, with user credentials, associate the laravel_token with the session still?

Comment: Since I do not know the answer the a) I suggest this via comment on b). You can use a Navigation Guard (https://www.storyblok.com/tp/how-to-auth0-vuejs-authentication#adding-a-navigation-guard) to check for the authentication state and/or your defined rules.